# iOSアプリのリリース作業中に、XCode のアーカイブをしても Productsフォルダが空になる

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

タイトルの通りですが、iOSアプリのリリース作業中に、XCode で Product → Archive をしたところ、
Details に Generic Xcode Archive と表示されて、「Validate Content」から先に進めません。

[image: XCodeのオーガナイザー画面]

生成されたアーカイブファイル（.xcarchive）の中身を見ると、Products の中身が空になっているので、これが原因ではないかと思うのですが、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか？

追記：
試しに新しいプロジェクトを作って、アーカイブしたところ、こちらは問題なくValidate Content ボタンも押せました。

XCode のバージョンは 11.4.1
Cocoapods は 1.9.1 です。

[image: アーカイブボタンを押して、生成された.xcarchive のパッケージ内]

Answer (score 1):

追記です

新しいプロジェクトを作って、全てのファイルを手動で移し替えたところ、うまく動くようになりました。
どこかの設定が間違っていたものと思います。
お騒がせしました。